# How to correctly set up rpy2?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to run rpy2 with no success. After installing R and rpy2, I tried testing rpy2 as instructed in the rp2 documentation:

from IDLE:

```
import rpy2.situation
for row in rpy2.situation.iter_info():
    print(row)
```

I'm getting the following output:

```
rpy2 version:
3.3.2
Python version:
3.8.2 (tags/v3.8.2:7b3ab59, Feb 25 2020, 22:45:29) [MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    InstallPath in the registry: C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0
    Environment variable R_USER: None
    Environment variable R_LIBS_USER: None
R version:
    In the PATH: None
    Loading R library from rpy2: cannot load library 'C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\x64\R.dll': error 0xc1
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
```

I set the environment variables that's not found as mentioned in the output, because I thought that maybe R's installation location is the issue, but it still doesn't work. I also looked for solutions for the R.dll error or dll files errors in general.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could use R interface integration with Python through a conda environment or a docker image. While the Docker approach is easier to set up, the conda approach is mainly because it allows you to manage different environments, in this case one with R and Python.

## 1. Using rpy2 with Docker Image

After **installing Docker** Desktop on your system, see this [link](https://docs.docker.com/get-docker/). You could use the [datasciencenotebook](https://hub.docker.com/r/jupyter/datascience-notebook/) image from Jupyter. Just type on your terminal

```
docker run -it -e GRANT_SUDO=yes --user root --rm -p 8888:8888 -p 4040:4040 -v D:/:/home/jovyan/work jupyter/datascience-notebook
```

if it's the first time running this command it will pull first the docker image. Notice that we're mounting the local directory `D:/` as a volume to the docker container. To allow this, **enable file sharing** inside Docker Desktop Settings, see the image below

[image]
Then, in a Jupyter Notebook cell just type `import rpy2`, rpy2 comes by default with this image.

[image]

## 2. Using rpy2 with Anaconda Environment

After succesfully [installing Anaconda distribution](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/), open the Anaconda prompt and **create a new conda environment**, in this case I'm calling it rpy2 environment.

`conda create -n rpy2-env r-essentials r-base python=3.7`

Notice that I'm including R and Python 3.7 for this environment. At the moment of writing, rpy2 is not yet compatible with the latest version of python. Then, **activate your environment and install rpy2**.

[image]

```
conda activate rpy2-env
conda install -c r rpy2
```

Now, you can use rpy2 by typing `python` or `ipython` on the terminal or through a Jupyter Notebook.

[image]

```
import rpy2.situation
for row in rpy2.situation.iter_info():
    print(row)
```

## 3. Installing R packages (Optional)

Additionally, if you need to install R packages, you could type in the terminal

`R -e install.packages("package_name")`

or inside a Jupyter Notebook

```
import rpy2.robjects.packages as rpackages
from rpy2.robjects.vectors import StrVector

# Choosing a CRAN Mirror
utils = rpackages.importr('utils')
utils.chooseCRANmirror(ind=1)

# Installing required packages
packages = ('ggplot', 'stats')
utils.install_packages(StrVector(packages))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your Python version is 32 bit and R version is 64 bit. Try linking to the R in the `bin\i386` instead of the `bin\x64` folder.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add the location of the `R.dll` library (x64 or i386 depending on whether you use python 32 or 64) to path.

From the error you got, this is in your case : `C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/bin/x64`

This is a common problem [observed with other libraries](https://github.com/Kozea/WeasyPrint/issues/971#issuecomment-544195744) and the solution is straight forward :

```
import os
os.environ['PATH'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-4.0.0/bin/x64' + os.pathsep + os.environ.get('PATH', '')
import rpy2.situation
for row in rpy2.situation.iter_info():print(row)

rpy2 version:
3.3.5
Python version:
3.7.4 (default, Aug  9 2019, 18:34:13) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)]
Looking for R's HOME:
    Environment variable R_HOME: None
    InstallPath in the registry: C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0
    Environment variable R_USER: None
    Environment variable R_LIBS_USER: None
R version:
    In the PATH: 
    Loading R library from rpy2: OK
Additional directories to load R packages from:
None
```